# Cannot install wordpress in XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, xampp, bitnami

I have successfully installed XAMPP. My Apache and MySQL server is running perfectly. 
When I am installing wordpress when the progress par is filling up there is no problem.

[image]

But when the progress bar at the end I get the following message in my XAMPP control panel and the installation won't complete. The status will be unpacking file.

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:53:49 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:53:49 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:53:49 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:53:49 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:53:49 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:53:49 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

[image]

So anyone got any tips to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you have to change the port for apache in order to install wordpress because may be they are both using the same port

this link has the method on how you can change the port for apache :

http://w3guy.com/fix-xampp-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/

i hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using an application for this simple action?

Follow these steps:

1. download wordpress form: https://wordpress.org/download/
2. extract it in htdocs (C:\xampp\htdocs)
3. create a mysql database and user
4. open wp folder in browser
5. follow the wizard.

I have shown how to do that in [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAQGfs5skyo). Watch the video for complete information.

Reply to me if you find any issue there.

Comment: Thank you for the YouTube video, it was super helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the WordPress installer or the module? You should install the module from https://bitnami.com/xampp

Answer (score 0):

by default Xammp has port 80 as port as well as other microsoft studio programs. in case of conflic of ports, you should change the xammp port and type in localhost:newport into your browser.

check in for a comprehesive tutorial... https://sourcecodepot.blogspot.co.ke/2016/11/how-to-install-wordpress-part-one.html

Answer (score -1):

After I struggled all morning trying install wordpress next to joomla and drupal into existing xamp I followed this procedure and it worked for me:

The installation hangs because of conflict while accessing http and https ports.
Installation of module starts its own httpd process, so kill it.
Use the Netstat tool for determining process which accesses those ports and kill it, then start apache from xamp console and the installation will continue after a while.